# arp-scanで取得したipアドレスへ一斉にpingを送りたい

Tags: python, shellscript

arp-scanで取得したipアドレスに一斉にpingを送る方法を模索しています。

一度ターミナルに出力された結果をテキストファイルに保存し、そこからpingを送ろうとしているのですが、上手くいきません。

python自体知識が全くないので、どのようなプログラムを書けばいいのかわかりません。
分かる方がいればお願いします。

下記にarp-scanの一例を記載しておきます。(一部変えています)

```
$ arp-scan -l
Interface: eth0, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
Starting arp-scan 1.4 with 256 hosts (http://www.nta-monitor.com/tools/arp-scan/)
192.168.0.1   00:11   Dell ESG PCBA Test
192.168.0.2   00:12   Intel Corporation
192.168.0.3   00:16   Dell Inc.
192.168.0.4   00:10   Juniper Networks, Inc.
192.168.0.5   00:01   Hewlett-Packard Company
192.168.0.6   00:04   Cisco Systems, Inc.
192.168.0.7   00:30:  HEWLETT-PACKARD
```

---

ipアドレスのみ抽出することは出来たのですが、ここから一括でpingを送る方法を考えています。
ipアドレスをリスト化？　してfor文で送ろうとしてみましたが、知識不足で動きませんでした。

```
import subprocess
cmd = "sudo arp-scan  -l |grep '192' | awk '{print $1}'"
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

実行結果

```
192.168.2.1
192.168.2.11
192.168.2.12
192.168.2.14
192.168.2.107
192.168.2.108
192.168.2.112
192.168.2.113
192.168.2.203
```

Comment: pingを送る方法、ではなくて、ipを取得する方法を聞きたいってことですよね？

Comment: @わわい `arp-scan`で取得したIPアドレスの一覧に対して`ping`を実行したい、ではありませんか？ / @ummm Pythonでの実行は必須でしょうか？

Comment: pythonは必須です。すみません

Comment: arp-scan に `-l` オプションを指定していますので、`grep '192'` は不要になります。なので、`sudo arp-scan -l -q -x | cut -f1 | xargs -n 1 ping` としても良かろうかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。pingを送ることは出来たのですが、一行目のipアドレスのみにpingを送っていて、複数のipアドレスには送れないのでしょうか？

Comment: 回数を指定したら順番に送ってくれました。本当にありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

参考までに、[fping](https://raspberry-projects.com/pi/software_utilities/fping) コマンドが使える環境なら以下の様なワンライナーで実行できます。

```
$ arp-scan -l | grep '^192' | awk '{ print $1 }' | fping -c 1
```

Comment: 有難うございます　試してみます。

Comment: 正常に動きました。有難うございます！